# Finding duplicates in SQL with filter

Tags: sql

In addition to finding duplicates, how can I filter using something like “and where primarysmtpaddress like ‘%@sub.domain.com’”

```
SELECT y.primarysmtpaddress, y.phonenumber
FROM UMEnabledAccounts y
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    phonenumber, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                    FROM UMEnabledAccounts
                    GROUP BY phonenumber
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
                )  dt ON y.phonenumber=dt.phonenumber order by PhoneNumber asc
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @vendettamit the full query will be

```
SELECT y.primarysmtpaddress, y.phonenumber
    FROM UMEnabledAccounts y
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        phonenumber, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                        FROM UMEnabledAccounts
                        where  primarysmtpaddress like '%@sub.domain.com'
                        GROUP BY phonenumber
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
                    )  dt ON y.phonenumber=dt.phonenumber order by PhoneNumber asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a where clause before group by. This will perform grouping on filtered rows only.

```
SELECT phonenumber, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM UMEnabledAccounts
where primarysmtpaddress like '%@sub.domain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT y.primarysmtpaddress, y.phonenumber
FROM UMEnabledAccounts y
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                phonenumber, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                FROM UMEnabledAccounts
                GROUP BY phonenumber
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
            )  dt 
          ON y.phonenumber=dt.phonenumber 
          WHERE primarysmtpaddress like ‘%@sub.domain.com’
          order by PhoneNumber asc;
```

The above query will create the join and then implements the where clause on the newly formed rows.